Create a dynamic react component using portal and promise
Call a modal or drawer from anywhere in my react app using simple a function.
I have made this work by using the root.render, but the problem with root.render they cannot found any of my previous providers, makeing me duplicate and import all providers again in this component. Is there a way to do this even if it's not with the portal?
The code from the function:
  const handleDelete = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await SheetManager(".KeyDrawerGlobal", "KeyEdit");

      console.log(res);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

And this is the SheetManager code:
import React from "react";
import _ from "lodash";
import SheetComponent from "./SheetRegister";
import { SwipeableDrawer } from "@mui/material";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";

const SheetManager = (container = "body", component = null, options = {}) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const parent = document.querySelector(container);
    if (!parent) return reject();
    const handleClose = (result) => {
      if (result) resolve({ result });

      reject();
    };

    createPortal(
      <SwipeableDrawer
        container={parent}
        anchor="bottom"
        open={true}
        onClose={handleClose}
        onOpen={() => {}}
        disableSwipeToOpen={false}
        ModalProps={{
          keepMounted: true,
          sx: {
            position: "absolute !important",
          },
          componentsProps: {
            backdrop: {
              sx: {
                position: "absolute !important",
              },
            },
          },
        }}
        PaperProps={{
          sx: {
            position: "absolute !important",
            borderTopLeftRadius: "16px",
            borderTopRightRadius: "16px",
          },
        }}
      >
        <SheetComponent type={component} {...options} />
      </SwipeableDrawer>,
      document.body
    );
  });
};

export default SheetManager;



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I created a solution by using it like a Context, here is the result:
import {
  SwipeableDrawer,
} from "@mui/material";
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";
import SheetComponent from "../components/core/sheet/SheetRegister";

const SheetContext = createContext();

export const useSheet = () => useContext(SheetContext);

let showSheet;

export const SheetProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [modal, setSheet] = useState(null);

  showSheet = (container = "body", component, props) => {
    const parent = document.querySelector(container);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const handleClose = (result) => {
        setSheet(null);
        if (result) resolve(result);
        else reject();
      };

      setSheet({ container: parent, component, props, handleClose });
    });
  };

  return (
    <SheetContext.Provider value={showSheet}>
      {children}
      {modal &&
        createPortal(
          <SwipeableDrawer
            container={modal.container}
            anchor="bottom"
            open={true}
            onClose={() => modal.handleClose()}
            onOpen={() => {}}
            disableSwipeToOpen={false}
            ModalProps={{
              keepMounted: true,
              sx: {
                position: "absolute !important",
              },
              componentsProps: {
                backdrop: {
                  sx: {
                    position: "absolute !important",
                  },
                },
              },
            }}
            PaperProps={{
              sx: {
                position: "absolute !important",
                borderTopLeftRadius: "16px",
                borderTopRightRadius: "16px",
              },
            }}
          >
            <SheetComponent
              type={modal.component}
              {...modal.props}
              handleClose={modal.handleClose}
            />
          </SwipeableDrawer>,
          modal.container
        )}
    </SheetContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { showSheet };


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
